# What does "off in " mean in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What does "off in " mean in the following sentences?

---

ex·fo·li·ate    v.

transitive verb

1 : to cast off in scales, laminae, or splinters

2 : to remove the surface of in scales or laminae

3 : to spread or extend by or as if by opening out leaves

intransitive verb

1 : to split into or give off scales, laminae, or body cells

2 : to come off in thin layers or scales

3 : to grow by or as if by producing or unfolding leaves

### (Source : Merriam-Webster dictionary )

A noun does not appear after a preposition, and another preposition appears after a preposition. In this case, is a noun after the preposition omitted?

Does "to cast ***off in*** scales, laminae, or splinters" mean "to cast off something
and something turn into scales, laminae, or splinters" ?

Does "to remove the surface ***of in*** scales or laminae " mean
"to remove the surface of something  and
surface of something turn into scales or laminae " ?

Does "to come ***off in*** thin layers or scales " mean "Something come off and
Something turn into thin layers or scales" ?

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they cannot be read by the software used by the visually impaired..

Comment: I have now modified the image of text into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does "to cast off in scales, laminae, or splinters" mean "to cast off
> something and something turn into scales, laminae, or splinters" ?

Not really. More like: "to cast off something, and that something which is being cast off, directly after it is cast off, takes the form of scales, laminae, or splinters."

> Does "to remove the surface of in scales or laminae " mean "to remove
> the surface of something and surface of something turn into scales or
> laminae " ?

No, this is incorrect English, and is incomprehensible.

> Does "to come off in thin layers or scales " mean "Something come off
> and Something turn into thin layers or scales" ?

More like: "the thing that is coming off is coming off in the form of layers of scales."

We are not necessarily saying that something is turning into something else. It could be that the scales were already scales. However, the word "in" does imply they are taking the form of scales and they might not have before.

Comment: Yes, "In" implies "in the form of something". The definition (I think) is to become separated from something in the form of "layers" or "scales".